# Removing duplicate legend items in QGIS?

Tags: legend, qgis-2.12, duplication

I work with several layers that share similar symbology partly. I'm trying to remove duplicate Symbology from the legend:

[image]

All the layer and their classification are in the map extent.
I try to use the filter legend [image]
but with no result

How can i do it automatically, at once?

Answer (score 1):

If you uncheck 'auto update',

[image]

you can remove individual legend items or groups.

[image]

Comment: but how can i do it automatically?

Comment: If you always work with the same legend, you can save that print composer as template. It will be stored as you defined and can use it afterwards.  For an automated way with other kinds of legends, this would be possible with python, I think.